# How to make an input field only as wide as there is space available?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table that looks like this:

[image]

Now when I add an input field to the second row in that table it becomes this:

[image]

So the second column becomes much wider, apparently the new input field extends its size. But I don't want that - instead I want the input field to take only as much space as there is already in that column, without widening it.

Is there a way via CSS to achieve this?

Comment: Can you post code?

Comment: Please show the code. Need to know how the column widths are set, among other things. Calc may be the answer: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: The table column will actually scale to fit the content, and if that input is all you have it will grow to fit it. You can try setting a width to the column if you want.

Comment: Give `width: 100%` to the input, this might help you

Comment: @NikhilSingh That's it, thanks a lot. It can be so easy... Will happily accept this answer if you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `width: 100%` to the input element.

Answer (score 0):

you can the following style, set table-layout to fixed

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

CSS

```css
th,td{
   border: 1px solid black;
}
table{
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>TRANING DATE</th>
  <th>CLIENT</th>
  <th>PROJECT</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input  />
  </td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```